# How to create a tree where it finds the correct node to add the children node?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

What's the best way to build a tree where the input gives the format `(a,b)`, `a` is the parent node and `b` is the children node? (node 1 is the root)
For example:

```
1 2 //adds node #2 as the children of #1 (the root)
1 3 //adds node #3 as the second children of the root
2 4 //adds node #4 as the children of node #2
etc...
```

I understand how to make this kind of tree if it is like a binary tree (since the left child is the lesser value and the right child is the the greater for a given parent node). But, the amount of children nodes a parent can have is not fixed for my tree. How can I create this efficiently? I'm having trouble understanding how the algorithm can iterate and find the correct node (the `a` part of the input) so that it can add another node as the children (the `b` part of the input) since the amount of children a node can have isn't fixed.

EDIT: Another thing I want to add: each leaf nodes (ones with no children nodes) will be assigned some values. I need to recursively (or some other method) traverse down the tree so that I can calculate the values of each node: the parent node value is the sum of all of its children node values.

Comment: Question is probably better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange

Comment: Can you prevent something like this from happening? 1 2, 2 1; Essentially a loop of parent->child, child->parent.

Answer (score 0):

store Right child and sibling addresses in each node.

when you receive `a,b`, if node `a` has not right child insert `b` as right child and if has right child follow the sibling of right child to find last child and insert `b` as sibling of the last node.

---

**Traversing the tree:**

I think this algorithm can traverse the tree in Depth First:

```
traverse(Node) 
 visit (Node) // pre order 
 if (Node.RightChild != Null)
  n = Node.RightChild
  while(n.LeftSibling != Null)
   traverse ( n.LeftSibling )
   n = n.LeftSibling
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: hmm... I thought about that but I have another problem now: after I build the tree, the leaf nodes (one where they don't have any children) will have a given input value (a different value than the values `(a,b)`). I need to somehow recursively calculate the values of each node where the parent node equals the sum of all of the values of the children node. Will that work for the method you provided?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually sufficient to store children nodes as a linked-list (or array) (although, depending on the type of tree, other representations may be more efficient).

Typically you'd have a map or array of nodes.

When you're looking for `a`, you'd simply do a lookup in the map or array for it.

Then you simply add `b` to the list of children.

> I need to recursively traverse down the tree

That would involve a simple [breadth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).